# Issue with TensorFlow Summary

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I tried to modify "`mnist_with_summaries.py`" for analyzing image data from my research.

When I tried to use TensorBoard for visualization, following error appeared (`0x2e414f0 Compute status: Out of range: Nan in summary histogram for: HistogramSummary`):

```
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1102] 0x2e414f0 Compute status: Out of range: Nan in summary histogram for: HistogramSummary
     [[Node: HistogramSummary = HistogramSummary[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](HistogramSummary/tag, weights/read)]]
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1102] 0x2e414f0 Compute status: Out of range: Nan in summary histogram for: HistogramSummary_1
     [[Node: HistogramSummary_1 = HistogramSummary[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](HistogramSummary_1/tag, bias/read)]]
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1102] 0x2e414f0 Compute status: Out of range: Nan in summary histogram for: HistogramSummary
     [[Node: HistogramSummary = HistogramSummary[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](HistogramSummary/tag, weights/read)]]
     [[Node: _send_train/ScatterUpdate_0 = _Send[T=DT_FLOAT, client_terminated=true, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1698099469756475374, tensor_name="train/ScatterUpdate:0", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](train/ScatterUpdate)]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "NeuralNetwork_TensorFlow.py", line 102, in main
    update_op_train, train_step], feed_dict=feed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 315, in run
    return self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 511, in _run
    feed_dict_string)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 564, in _do_run
    target_list)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 586, in _do_call
    e.code)
OutOfRangeError: Nan in summary histogram for: HistogramSummary
     [[Node: HistogramSummary = HistogramSummary[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](HistogramSummary/tag, weights/read)]]
Caused by op u'HistogramSummary', defined at:
  File "NeuralNetwork_TensorFlow.py", line 124, in <module>
    main()
  File "NeuralNetwork_TensorFlow.py", line 58, in main
    w_hist = tf.histogram_summary("weights", W)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/summary_ops.py", line 60, in histogram_summary
    tag=tag, values=values, name=scope)
  File "/usr/lrflow/python/ops/gen_summary_ops.py", line 34, in _histogram_summary
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 655, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2040, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1087, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()ocal/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_summary_ops.py", line 34, in _histogram_summary
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 655, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2040, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1087, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()
```

I was wondering why ? what does this "Out of range" mean ?

Here is part of my modified code:

```py
...
sess = tf.Session()

#training data
trainDS = trainds.read_data_sets(ins_size, step);
testDS = testds.read_data_sets(img, ins_size, step)

batch_num  = testDS.test.ylength
batch_size = testDS.test.xlength

# Create the model
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, ins_size**2*3], name = "x_input")
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, label_option], name="y_input") 
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([ins_size**2*3,label_option]), name = "weights")
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([label_option]), name = "bias")

with tf.name_scope("Wx_b") as scope:
  y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)

#Add summary ops to collect data
w_hist = tf.histogram_summary("weights", W)
b_hist = tf.histogram_summary("biases", b)
... ...
merged_train = tf.merge_summary([w_hist, b_hist]) 
writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter("/tmp/neuralnetwork_logs", \
                   sess.graph.as_graph_def(add_shapes=True))
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()    
sess.run(init)

#train
for i in range(batch_num):
  batch_xs, batch_ys = trainDS.train.next_batch(batch_size)
  feed = {x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys, batch_index: i}
  if i % 100 == 0:  # Record summary data
    result = sess.run([merged_train, \
       update_op_train, train_step], feed_dict=feed)
    writer.add_summary(result[0], i)
  else:
    sess.run([update_op_train, train_step], feed_dict=feed)

sess.close()
... ...
```

Please help me!

Comment: You can get NaN's when your training diverges

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov do you mean that the problem might come from my training data ?

Comment: You could get divergence even if data is fine, I would try printing your cost and seeing if it goes to infinity, and also lowering learning rate

Comment: Thank you very much! I think that is the problem! Just tried to print the variables, the value is indeed NaN.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov another  quick question. Just wondering do you know what is the `input_` in the `tf.Print(input_, data, message=None, first_n=None, summarize=None, name=None)` function ? I know data is the variables I need to print, but what is input_?  I got confused by the API document ("A tensor passed through this op")

Comment: Tf.print creates a node, and the print happens only when that node is executed. You can force it to be executed by making use of the output value  of that node by taking another value and "passing it through" the node

Comment: Ie something like loss=tf.Print(loss, [loss], "printing loss")

Comment: I was also getting the same error. Lowering the learning rate as mentioned by @YaroslavBulatov worked for me...